# What is the difference between WHERE P=B.N... AS B and WHERE P=N?

Tags: mysql

I was working on this hackerrank task - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem

I came up with this solution with a little "Discussions" help:

```
SELECT N, 
CASE 
    WHEN P IS NULL THEN "Root"
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P=B.N) > 0 THEN "Inner"
    ELSE "Leaf"
END
FROM BST AS B
ORDER BY N;
```

Im wondering why "`P=B.N... AS B`" is needed here and what difference this actually makes. Why does `WHERE P=N` fail?

Comment: Where does p come from where does n come from , are there n in both tables? what doe s fail mean(error or does not produce what you want) Please don't include external links in questions I for one have no inclination to sign up to view the question.

Comment: Yes, its all explained in the task - https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-challenge-images/12888/1443818467-30644673f6-2.png

You dont need to sign up. Just click somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

When you omit "B" it will look in the subselect "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST" not in BST from the main query "FROM BST AS B".